# What is the value of this product (with gamma and zeta function)?

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, gamma-function

Since $\zeta(s)=0$ and $\Gamma(s)$ has poles at even negative numbers $-2, -4, -6...$ Can we find a value for $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)}$ using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)?

Comment: The command of Mathematica `Limit[1/Zeta[s]/Gamma[s], s -> -2*n, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]` produces $$ \frac{(2 n)!}{\zeta '(-2 n)}.$$

Comment: @user64494 Thank you.

Comment: The functional equation for $\zeta(s)$ gives a formula for $\zeta(n)$, $n=0,-1,-2,\cdots$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers.  As you mentioned, this formula just gives 0 for negative even integers.  The value you are interested in is equivalent to computing $\zeta(3), \zeta(5), \cdots$, but these are much more mysterious, with no closed formulae.  In fact, despite there being a closed formula for even natural numbers, just proving that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational ended up a very subtle argument by Apery, and there are few irrationality results for the others.